# Email with text/html but without plain/text

Tags: email, html-email, email-client

I am writing a software to send transactional emails and I had several issues when it comes to sending emails with plain/text and text/html.

I know that it is not advised to send emails without plain/text portion but I am really considering it.

So, here is my question. Nowadays, is it a concern if I send emails with text/html but without plain/text portion?

I have tested it with Gmail, Hotmail, and Microsoft Outlook (via Microsoft Exchange) and it worked very well so far.

Thanks,

Comment: It will fail for anyone who sets their mail client to display text-only emails, or for any organisation that explicitly strips HTML emails from their mail traffic. People do this for very good security reasons

Comment: Older Blackberrys cannot display HTML at all, so if your audience includes those users they will see nothing.

Comment: If you're able to write such a software, you can write small code (or find it on many open source projects) to convert HTML text to plain text.

Comment: Instead of resorting to this, maybe make a question with the issues you've encountered sending emails with text/plain and text/html. Who knows, you might find a solution (though I guess it's a bit late for that though).

Comment: Yes, I did. It was solved in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17097806/send-email-via-smtp-with-attachment-plain-text-and-text-hml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, old devices may not be able to display text-only format properly as mentioned by samanthasquered. But, in my case mail-filters (spam filters or any filter created manually as mentioned by Mike W) would be a bigger concern.

Here is the best reference I could find about this topic: http://blog.hubspot.com/blog/tabid/6307/bid/32643/Why-Marketers-Must-Optimize-Emails-for-HTML-AND-Plain-Text-Infographic.aspx

Thanks,