# Send email via SMTP with attachment, plain/text, and text/hml

Tags: email, smtp, jakarta-mail, html-email, email-attachments

**My goal:** Send transactional emails via SMTP with plain/text, text/html, and attachments.

**My code:** Implemented with JavaMail

**My issue:** It looks fine on hotmail, or outlook. But on **gmail**, it does not show the message body properly if it is an email with a .txt attachment (it works alright if attachments are images)

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Here is my raw SMTP output:

```
Subject: ALTERNATIVE | TXT | HTML |ATT.ATTACHMENT | Thu Jun 13 17:48:04 EDT
 2013
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; 
    boundary="----=_Part_0_21791733.1371160084561"

------=_Part_0_21791733.1371160084561
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Body message in text format!
------=_Part_0_21791733.1371160084561
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Body message in <b>html</b> format! Sent on Thu Jun 13 17:48:04 EDT 2013<br> to: me@gmail.com<br> to: me@mijo.com<br> cc: me@hotmail.com<br> cc: rafael.santos.test@hotmail.com
------=_Part_0_21791733.1371160084561
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii; name=email_attachment.txt
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=email_attachment.txt

This is a text attachment file!
------=_Part_0_21791733.1371160084561--
.
250 Delivery in progress
QUIT
```

**Some screenshots**

Sent with only one .txt attachment. The message body does not display and attachment are duplicated.

[image]

Same message but with different attachment (.gif). Everything looks fine.
[image]

***=== SOLUTION FOR JAVA DEVELOPERS ====***

The overall idea is described here: http://www.coderanch.com/t/503380/java/java/Java-Mail-text-html-attachment

So, now my code looks like:

```
// contentPart is the content to be sent. It is divided in bodyContent and attachmentContent
            MimeMultipart contentPart = new MimeMultipart("mixed");

            // Message body in txt and html format
            MimeMultipart bodyPart = new MimeMultipart("alternative");
            // Creates plain text message
            BodyPart bodyTxt = new MimeBodyPart();
            bodyTxt.setText(getMessageBodyText());
            // Creates html message
            BodyPart bodyHtml = new MimeBodyPart();
            bodyHtml.setContent(getMessageBodyHtml(), "text/html");
            bodyPart.addBodyPart(bodyTxt);
            bodyPart.addBodyPart(bodyHtml);

            // Wrapper for bodyTxt and bodyHtml
            MimeBodyPart bodyContent = new MimeBodyPart();
            bodyContent.setContent(bodyPart);

            // At this point, contentPart contains bodyTxt and bodyHtml wrapped in a multipart/alternative
            contentPart.addBodyPart(bodyContent);

            // Adds attachments to contentPart
            if (getAttachments() != null) {
                for(File f : getAttachments()) {
                    try {
                        MimeBodyPart attachmentPart = new MimeBodyPart();
                        attachmentPart.attachFile(f);
                        contentPart.addBodyPart(attachmentPart);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        logger.severe("Could not attach file to email!" +
                                " TO: "+ getTo().toString() +
                                "; CC: "+ getCc().toString() +
                                "; ExceptionMessage: " + e.getMessage());
                        throw new SmtpRequestException(e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The structure of your message is wrong.  You need nested multiparts to get the right structure, something like this:

```
  multipart/mixed
    multipart/alternative (holding the two forms of the body part)
      text/plain
      text/html
    text/plain or image/gif (the attachment)
```

Comment: That's right. Actually, I implemented the solution for this issue a little before seeing your answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: What if some of the attachments are actually pictures, embedded in the text/html part? What does the right structure looks like, then? Can I simply replaced "mixed" with "related"? Or do I have to use different subparts for the "related" attachments with INLINE disposition, and "mixed" for the rest? I am VERY confused... :(

Comment: Keep with mixed. The answer presented here worked greatly with text and binary files.

Comment: If the text/html part is referencing the images using "cid:" references, they all should be in a multipart/related.  Don't replace the multipart/mixed in the example above.  Instead, replace the text/html with a multipart/related that includes the text/html and the image/jpg that it references.  Let me know if that's not clear.

Comment: Your hierarchy looks as if you're attaching a `Multipart` to a `Multipart`. Specifically, how is a `multipart/alternative` Object attached to a `multipart/mixed` Object?

Comment: `Multipart mp = new MimeMultipart(); Multiaprt mpa = new MimeMultipart("alternative"); MimeBodyPart mbp = new MimeBodyPart(); mbp.setContent(mpa); mp.addBodyPart(mbp);
`