# How to Send, WITHOUT INTENTS, an EMail with a FILE, in internal storage, as Attachment in Android programatically?

Tags: java, android, email, email-attachments

So I'm using the following code to create and write data into a **file**:

```
    String filename1 = "transaction.txt";
    String data = "The data to be sent"
    try {
        FileOutputStream fOs = openFileOutput(filename1,MODE_PRIVATE);
        fOs.write(data.getBytes());
        fOs.close();
        Log.v("FILE","Files have been written");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

*Simple so far..*

So, how do I send this **file "transaction.txt"** as an **Attachment** to and from any **GMAIL** account?

> **You can Ignore the below part if it confuses you, but, below lies code of how I use the JavaMail API to send a message:**

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

Session session = null;
ProgressDialog pdialog = null;
Context context = null;
EditText reciep, sub, msg;
String rec, subject, textMessage;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    context = this;

    Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);
    reciep = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_to);
    sub = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_sub);
    msg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_text);

    login.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    rec = reciep.getText().toString();
    subject = sub.getText().toString();
    textMessage = msg.getText().toString();

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

    session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication("XXXXX@gmail.com", "XXXXXX");
        }
    });

    pdialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "", "Sending Mail...", true);

    RetreiveFeedTask task = new RetreiveFeedTask();
    task.execute();
}

class RetreiveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        try{
            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("testfrom354@gmail.com"));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(rec));
            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setContent(textMessage, "text/html; charset=utf-8");
            Transport.send(message);
        } catch(MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        pdialog.dismiss();
        reciep.setText("");
        msg.setText("");
        sub.setText("");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
    }
```

> THIS **email part** is very **easy** actually, but I am **open to changes**....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Intent for sending email with attachment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6078099/android-intent-for-sending-email-with-attachment)

Comment: Without intent? How about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17156544/sending-an-email-with-an-attachment-using-javamail-api

Comment: @cricket_007 , OK, thanks, but I want for android, and also, how do i implement that class or what ever...like how do i send mail after i import that class into my code?

Comment: Java is Java. `Transport.send(message);` sends the mail. You need to attach a multi part body to the message from the file

Comment: @cricket_007 , bro, please explain the following:

1) Where must I Enter the from address and password
2) Where must I enter the To Addresses
3) Where must I Enter the subject, Body and Attachment FIle("transaction.txt")
4) and finally how do i send it when I click a button?(Inside the OnCLick)

Comment: Don't you already have the from, to, subject, and body in the AsyncTask of your question?