# Sending email without Intent.createChooser and with attachment

Tags: android, email, android-intent

I would like to send an email with attachment directly from my app without opening an email client on user's device. How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You may do this using [Gmail authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2033124/4378400), for example.

You need to have an account from which the emails will be sent. In other words, an SMTP server that you have access to and a permission to use.

To send an email with attachments, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17156544/sending-an-email-with-an-attachment-using-javamail-api). You will need to modify the code that you got in Gmail authentication, and add multipart data to the message.