# Javamail adding attachment prevent mail to be sent

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, attachment

I'm struggling with Javamail, I'm trying to send emails with a zip file attached.
When I try to send a mail without attachment, it works fine but when I add the zip the mail is no longer sent. I have no errors...

My code :

```
LOGGER.info("########################### Send Email with attachement to " + destination + "  Start ######################");
    //Config smtp mail
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", getSmtpHost());
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", getSmtpsocketFactoryPort());
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", getSmtpsocketFactoryClass());
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", getSmtpAuth());
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", getSmtpPort());

    //instance Session
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(getUsername(), getPassword());
        }
    });

    try {
        //construction objet mail
        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(getFromAddress()));

        //Send Email to Addresse
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(destination));
        message.setSubject(objet);
        message.setSentDate(new Date());

        MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        messageBodyPart.setText(contenu);

        MimeBodyPart  attachmentBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        String fileName = attachementPath + attachementName;
        File file = new File (fileName);
        attachmentBodyPart.attachFile(file); 

        MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
        multipart.addBodyPart(attachmentBodyPart);

        message.setContent(multipart);
        //send Email
        Transport.send(message);
        LOGGER.info("########################### Send email with attachement to " + destination + " End ########################### ");
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error when send email to " + destination);
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

I've tryied a lot of things, I may be to tired to find the mistake xD

Thanks for the help !!

**Update** : Thanks to jmehrens I've found the issue. My mail server doesn't allow .zip

Comment: "when I add the zip the mail is no longer sent." look suspicious you probably have some exception somewhere. BTW, what is the point of `new StringBuilder(attachementPath + attachementName).toString()` ???

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/q/17097806/180100 could help

Comment: Does your mail server have a policy on not allowing files that end with`.zip`?  You should be able to test that with just a mail client or rename the extension.

Comment: @jmehrens thank you ! I just tried with a .txt and it work ! It's the first time I use Javamail so I was assuming that I made a mistake....

Comment: @RC. I did a StringBuilder because I was tired and I thought that String = String + String wasn't working...

Comment: ?! yes it does: https://ideone.com/4zPQym

Comment: @RC. I removed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your mail server doesn't have a policy in place that prevents the delivery of emails with the extension of `.zip`.  You should be able to test that with just a mail client (or JavaMail) and rename the extension to either `.txt` or even `.piz`.

Read the [JavaMail FAQ](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ).  It is full of good information on best practices, debugging and troubleshooting steps.