# Send an HTML email with an attachment in unix either using mail,mailx or sendmail

Tags: email, unix

I am  trying to  send  an  HTML  email  along   with  few  attachments, but i when  m  not   using 
**Content-Type: text/html**
in header then i  am  able to send  the   attachment , but HTML  part  of  the  email is   displayed as  below :-

```
<html>
<body>
<p>This  is  the  body  content</p>
</body>
</html>
```

but when  m using  the
**Content-Type: text/html**  in header  am   able   to  see the HTML  part  of  the  email  as  below :-

This is  the body  content

But in this case  m not able to send the attachment.

Below  is  the   2 sets   of   code   am  using 
For  set  1 :-

```
FILES="$(ls /dir_with_the_list_of_files_to_be_sent  | awk  '{print $0}' | tr '\n' ' ')"  
(
echo "To: abc@abc.com"
echo "Subject:Extract List ";
echo "Content-Type: text/html"
echo
echo "<html>"
echo "<body>"
echo "<font face='Courier New' size='1'>"
echo "<h1>Hi All,</h1>"
echo "<h1>Below are the path  </h1>"
echo "<br>"
echo "<font size="4"><p>Thanks & Regards,<br />
<br />
echo "`for f in $FILES ; do uuencode "$f" "$f" ; done `"
ABC</p></font>"
echo "</font>"
echo "</body>"
echo "</html>"

) | /usr/sbin/sendmail -t
```

For   set  2 :-

```
FILES="$(ls /dir_with_the_list_of_files_to_be_sent  | awk  '{print $0}' | tr '\n' ' ')"  
(
echo "To: abc@abc.com"
echo "Subject:Extract List ";
echo
echo "<html>"
echo "<body>"
echo "<font face='Courier New' size='1'>"
echo "<h1>Hi All,</h1>"
echo "<h1>Below are the path  </h1>"
echo "<br>"
echo "<font size="4"><p>Thanks & Regards,<br />
<br />
echo "`for f in $FILES ; do uuencode "$f" "$f" ; done `"
ABC</p></font>"
echo "</font>"
echo "</body>"
echo "</html>"

) | /usr/sbin/sendmail -t
```

Could   someone  please  suggest  how  can  i send both  the  HTML  part  of   email  and  attachment  from unix.

Thanks   in  advance.

Comment: You can't just print attachments into the message. You need to use multipart, see for example this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17097806/send-email-via-smtp-with-attachment-plain-text-and-text-hml

Comment: Thanks  James... But  it seems   in unix  its  not  possible  to  send multiple  attachments   along  with  HTML.
I tried   an  alternative  and zipped  the   files  to  be   sent   and  then used  sendmail  to  send  the emal  with  one  zip  attachment

Comment: I'm quite sure there is no such limitation. You should update your question with the latest code.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for helping  on my question.